# Accessing two fields of a line before a matched line

Tags: awk

Given the following in a file, `file.txt`:

```
Line with asdfgh output1 45 output2 80
Special Header
Line with output1 38 output2 99
Special Header
```

I would like to print to a file:

```
45 80
38 99
```

i.e., in the line immediately preceding lines whose first column is `Special`, store the number (which can be a `float` type with decimals) after `output1` and `output2`

I tried:

```
awk '($1 == "Special" ) {printf f; printf ("\n");} {f=$0}' file.txt > output.txt
```

This captures the entirety of the previous line and I get `output.txt` which looks like this:

```
Line with output1 45 output2 80
Line with output1 38 output2 99
```

Now, within the captured variable `f`, how can I access the specific values after `output1` and `output2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++)
  if ($i == "output1") {arr[NR]=$(i+1)}
  else if ($i == "output2") {arr[NR]=arr[NR]" "$(i+1)}}
  ($1 == "Special") {print arr[NR-1]}
' file
```

### Output

```
45 80
38 99
```

Comment: Yes, this indeed works, however, the numbers are not always in the 4th and 6th column. They are after `output1` and `output2` in the previous line...so, is there a way to avoid the hardcoding of the column numbers?

Comment: @Inian that is not an issue in my particular case...the `Special` keyword is always going to have the line before which contains `output1` followed by a number and `output2` follower by another number.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU awk`:

```bash
$ awk '$1=="Special"{print m[1], m[2]}
       {match($0, /output1\s+(\S+).*output2\s+(\S+)/, m)}' ip.txt
45 80
38 99
```

With `perl`:

```bash
$  perl -ne 'print "@d\n" if /^Special/; @d = /output[12]\s+(\S+)/g' ip.txt
45 80
38 99
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '$1=="Special"{print x, y} {x=$(NF-2); y=$NF}' file
45 80
38 99
```

Comment: Thanks. This was also the first suggested answer in the accepted answer. I had wanted to avoid hardcoding the column numbers since they are fluid.

Comment: Then provide more truly representative sample input in your question that demonstrates that fluiditiy.

Comment: I believe I was quite specific in the wording in the OP immediately following the sample file and sample output: `in the line immediately preceding lines whose first column is Special, store the number (which can be a float type with decimals) after output1 and output2`
However, your point is well made and my sample files could have been improved.
Have edited my OP to reflect that!

Comment: I updated my answer to match your new example.